# Rails: Need help understanding a join table, nested forms, associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I'm a student learning Rails, and my project is to make a Recipes app. My recipes app has models `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, and other things, but the important thing is that an `Ingredient` must be the only ingredient of it's kind in the table. A row would be just an id and name. There can be only one "rice" in the table, so any `Recipe` that uses rice as an ingredient, uses that same row. That way (I guess) I can filter `Recipe`s by `Ingredient`s.

I have to use a nested form when creating/editing a `Recipe`, so the user can fill out the recipe info and ingredients all in one screen, including adding new `Ingredients`, and choosing ingredients from a drop list to select. In edit, the user can also delete (disassociate) and `Ingredient` from a `Recipe`.

I understand that I will need a join table (recipes_ingredients?? if so, what is the model called, `RecipesIngredient`?

I don't really understand how this nested form will work. I am to create a `fields_for` for all `Ingredient`s? How do disassociate and create?

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction where I can read about this. I've been racking my brain for a long time, even starting the project over twice. I'm getting frustrated but I feel like I'm so close to understanding it.

I also tried using simple_form and cocoon, but I feel like that just confused me even more.

Any light shed on this subject would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is broad. Try setting up your models with `has_many through` association and go for `cocoon` gem to setup your nested form. If you already tried this approach, update your question, explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly typical join table setup:

[image]

Here we have a normalized table named `ingredients` which serves as the master record for an ingredient and `recipe_ingredients` which joins with the `recipe` table.

In Rails we will set this up as a `has_many through:` association:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

The reason you want to use [`has_many through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and not `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that the later is "headless" as there is no model. Which might seem like a good idea until you realize that the is no way to access additional columns (like for example the quantity).

When naming join tables for `has_many through:` you should follow the scheme of `[thing in singular]_[thing in plural]` due to the way that Rails resolves class names from table names. Using `recipes_ingredients` for example would result in a missing constant error as Rails would attempt to load `Recipes::Ingredient`. The join model itself should be named `SingularSingular`.

You can of course also name join tables whatever fits the domain.

To add the nested rows you would use [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and `fields_for :recipe_ingredients`:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Ingredients</legend>
    <%= fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri| %>
    <div class="nested_fields">
       <div class="field">
         <%= ri.label :ingredient %>
         <%= ri.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
       </div>
       <div class="field">
         <%= ri.number_field :quantity %>
       </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

However nested fields are in many ways a cludge to allow the creation / modification of several models at once. The UX and application flow of moshing everything together is hardly ideal.

To provide a good UX its probably a better idea to apply incremental saves (the user saves the recipe before adding ingredients in the background with AJAX) and add the ingredients through a series of ajax POST requests to `/recipies/:recipe_id/ingredients`. But this is the subject of entire tutorial on its own and should most likely be revisited after you understand the basics.

See:

- [ActionController::StrongParameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)
- [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this write-up - it has helped me immensely understand joins, naming conventions, and forms. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

With simple words you describing the many-to-many associations.

So first off all take a look at the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

You need 3 models. The Recipe model , the Ingredient model and the Recipe_Ingredient model.

Ι guess you already have the two models, Recipe and Ingredient so lets see the join table-model.

First generate a migration :

```
rails generate migration create_recipe_ingredients
```

At `db/migrate/***create_recipe_ingredients.rb` create the connection table

```
def change
 create_table :recipe_ingredients do |t|
   t.integer :ingredient_id, :recipe_id
 end
end
```

So your models :

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many:recipe_ingredients
  has_many:ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients 
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many:recipe_ingredients
  has_many:recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

Run and test the associations at your console :

```
irb:> recipe=Recipe.first
irb:> ingre=Ingredient.first
irb:> ingre.recipes << recipe
irb:> ingre.recipes #Recipes with this ingredient
irb:> recipe.ingredients #The ingredients of this specific recipe.
irb:> Ingredient.all #List all your ingredients.
irb:> Recipe.all #List all your recipes.
```

Comment: Wow this was super super helpful. Thanks for the write up. Now I’m on to figuring out the nested forms using cocoon and simple form. Thanks again!